# NUnit Assert function to test if query executed successfully

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

How to unit test a query with assert function? The below piece of code runs a query and I want to test the result with Assertion.

```
try
   {
     string query = "SELECT \"NAME\", \"CITY\", \"AGE\" FROM MY_DB..EMPLOYEE";
     cmd.CommandText = query;
     dotNETDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     while (rdr.HasRows)
       {
         rdr.Read();
         System.Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetString(0));
         System.Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetString(1));
         System.Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetInt32(2));
         Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", rdr.GetValue(0), rdr.GetValue(1));
                    
       }
         rdr.Close();
         con.Close();
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
    System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
   }
```

Comment: you should return something from your method so that you can check in the test code. You are selecting the data by executing the query but not doing anything with the data in the reader... this code is not useful in any realtime scenario.

Comment: How to return after the query is executed?

Comment: What Chetan means: you wrote _[...] I want to test the result [...]_  - but what is your result? At the moment, you're only iterating through your data and printing them to the console. It would be different if you'd have something like `yield return new Result(rdr.GetValue(0), rdr.GetValue(1));`